# How to get server certificate information with SocketsHttpHandler in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, dotnet-httpclient

My service uses SocketHttpHandler to download web contents and sends back to clients. I am trying to pass server certificate information, too.
I know that SocketsHttpHandler has a property to specify a callback for validating a server certificate (SslClientAuthenticationOptions.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback) and its prototype is:

```
RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate? certificate, 
                                    X509Chain? chain, 
                                    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
```

with 'sender' being an SslStream object.

With the above signature, I couldn't figure out how to pass the information back to the client?
It looks like HttpClientHandler is able to do it, since the first parameter of its callback is HttpRequestMessage.

Is there any way to achieve the goal with SocketsHttpHandler?